# Splitting a string on ! in JAVA

Tags: java, split

```
for (String retval: text.split("\\!\\.\\?")) 
{
}
```

---

```
String text1 = "she said i know that she likes english food!";
```

Trying to split the text at ! . ? but the above doesn't seem to work and cant split on !

OUTPUT :
Preprocessing generated `[she, said, i, know, that, she, likes, english, food!]` but the expected result was `[she, said, i, know, that, she, likes, english, food, </s>]` ==> array contents differ at index [8], expected: `<food>` but was: `<food!>`

Answer (score 2):

`text.split("\\!\\.\\?")` splits on a consecutive `!`, `.` and `?`, which is not what you want

Instead use:

```
text.split("[!.?]")
```

***Output:*** (Input: `"This! is a lot? of words. separated by! punctuation?"`)

```
[This,  is a lot,  of words,  separated by,  punctuation]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this

```
    String[] array = text1.split("!|\\.|\\?|\\s");
```

You need to include | (or operator), this will split on ! or . or ? or a space character.
This should give you the result of [she, said, i, know, that, she, likes, english, food]